# Check if a bool? is True in Dynamic Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm doing a search form that has a few different options and have it all working except this one part.

For reference I'm posting the entire method but the issue I'm having is trying to do a dynamic expression to check a `bool?` property.

This line of code is where I'm having the problem...

```
call = Expression.IsTrue(propertyAccess); //TODO: Check if the property is true
```

As written it complains about `bool` to `bool?` conversion. If I change it to a `bool` instead of `bool?` it complains that `IsTrue is not a valid Linq expression`.

Basically I want to do `x => x.UltrasonicTest == true` but don't know how to set that to a `MethodCallExpression`.

Here is the short version of the code...

```
public ActionResult Search(List<string> selectedTests)
    {
        IQueryable<Logbook> logbooks;
        Expression lambdaStatus = null;
        Expression lambdaTests = null;
        Expression lambdaFinal = null;

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Logbook), "logbook");
        Expression call = null;
        PropertyInfo property = null;

        property = typeof(Logbook).GetProperty("UltrasonicTest");

        if (property != null)
        {
            MemberExpression propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
            call = Expression.IsTrue(propertyAccess); //TODO: Check if the property is true

            lambdaTests = call;
        }

        lambdaFinal = Expression.And(lambdaStatus, lambdaTests);

        Expression<Func<Logbook, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Logbook, bool>>(lambdaFinal, parameter);
        logbooks = db.Logbooks.Where(predicate);

        List<Logbook> filteredLogbooks = logbooks.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateEntered.Value).Take(50).ToList();

        return View("Index", filteredLogbooks);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `variable.HasValue && variable.Value` or `variable.GetValueOrDefault()` ?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `x => x.UltrasonicTest`? What about checking if `x.UltrasonicTest == true == true`, and so on?

Comment: Posting this huge wall of code is not going to help you get an answer. You should only post the minumum amount of code that reproduces the error. There is too much code in your method that is not relevant to the question you asked.

Comment: Shortened the code for clarity.

Comment: I've tried the normal code suggested above. The syntax won't work with trying to set it equal to the the expression variable.

Comment: If in doubt look at what the C# compiler generates and replicate that. Solves 99% of these questions.

Comment: This code is building a where clause so logbook.ultrasonic = true is what i'm needing. The error is thrown when i add it back to the query but points to this expression we are creating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than attempting to create a `MethodCallExpression` try constructing a `BinaryExpression` with the right as a `Constant` of `true`.

Something like this:

```
call = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, propertyAccess, Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool?)));
```

**Edit**

Or tidier option:

```
call = Expression.Equal(propertyAccess, Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool?)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If `UltrasonicTest` is a `bool?`, you have to make a decision about what value to return if it is null. If you simply want the lambda to return whether the property is not null **and** is true, you can create the following expression:

```
x => x.UltrasonicTest.GetValueOrDefault()
```

Assuming I wanted to create this expression from scratch, here's how I would make it:

```
var param = new ParameterExpression(typeof(Logbook), "x");
var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "UltraSonicTest");
var valOrDefault = Expression.Call(prop, "GetValueOrDefault", null);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<LogBook, bool>>(valOrDefault, param);
```

Comment: I tried this but got this error...

The binary operator And is not defined for the types 'System.Boolean' and 'System.Func`2[PB.Web.Models.Logbook,System.Boolean]'

Also the resulting lambda expression is {logbook => logbook.UltrasonicTest.GetValueOrDefault()} where I expected it to be {logbook => logbook.UltrasonicTest.GetValueOrDefault() == true}

Comment: @BradleyGatewood `logbook => logbook.UltrasonicTest.GetValueOrDefault() == true` doesn't make any sense. `GetValueOrDefault` will already return a bool, so why would you compare a bool to true to get the same bool? What about testing whether `logbook.UltrasonicTest.GetValueOrDefault() == true == true`, or `logbook.UltrasonicTest.GetValueOrDefault() == true == true == true`?

Comment: @BradleyGatewood Regarding the error you're getting, what line is it on?